# SQL Loop through table, get max number and increment at insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, and I'm looping though table1 to see if any records from table2 exists in there. If the `table1.IMAGE_NUMBER` already exists for that person, add `max(table2.IMAGE_NUMBER) + table1.IMAGE_NUMBER` before inserting a new record, otherwise just insert without incrementing the `IMAGE_NUMBER`.

The goal is to not have duplicate `IMAGE_NUMBER`
Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @NAME NVARCHAR(50), @ID INT, @IMAGE_NUMBER INT, AGE INT 
DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR FOR SELECT NAME, IMAGE_NUMBER, AGE FROM PEOPLE

OPEN MY_CURSOR   
FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @NAME, @ID, @IMAGE_NUMBER, @AGE 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN
    
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT R.NAME, RG.ID, R.IMAGE_NUMBER, R.DOB, R.PHONE
        FROM REGISTRATION R
        LEFT JOIN PEOPLE P ON R.ID = P.ID
        WHERE P.NAME = R._NAME
        AND P.IMAGE_NUMBER = R.IMAGE_NUMBER
        AND P.IS_ACTIVE = 1)

    BEGIN 
        -- how do I increment the image_number + max(R.IMAGE_NUMBER) from registration???
        INSERT INTO REGISTRATION(NAME, IMAGE_NUMBER, DOB, AGE)
        VALUES(@NAME, @IMAGE_NUMBER, @DOB, @AGE)
        
    END
    
    ELSE IF EXIST(SELECT R.NAME, RG.ID, R.IMAGE_NUMBER, R.DOB, R.PHONE
        FROM REGISTRATION R
        LEFT JOIN PEOPLE P ON R.ID = P.ID
        WHERE P.NAME = R._NAME
        AND P.IMAGE_NUMBER = R.IMAGE_NUMBER
        AND P.IS_ACTIVE = 1)
        
    BEGIN
    
     UPDATE REGISTRATION SET DATE_PROCESSED=GETUTCDATE()
     
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @NAME, @ID, @IMAGE_NUMBER, @AGE 
END   
CLOSE MY_CURSOR   
DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you wouldn't bother storing an actual number per each `NAME`. Just use `ROW_NUMBER` to calculate a numbering when you query it.

---

Be that as it may, there are quite a few issues with your current code:

- There is absolutely no need for a cursor (there rarely is), you can do this in one batch operation.
- Even if you wanted a cursor there are major bugs which would prevent your code from working.
- Your first `EXISTS` isn't actually comparing each row, it's comparing all rows, so it wouldn't work anyway.
- `LEFT JOIN` followed by `WHERE` on the same table converts it to an `INNER JOIN` logically.
- Unclear why you need both `DOB` and `AGE`, in fact I don't know why you would store age at all given you can calculate it from the DOB.
- Unclear why you have a separate `UPDATE` statement

I'm not exactly sure of your table schema, but it seems you want something like this.

```sql
INSERT INTO REGISTRATION (NAME, IMAGE_NUMBER, DOB, AGE, DATE)
SELECT
  P.NAME,
  ISNULL(R.MAX_NUMBER + 1, P.IMAGE_NUMBER),
  P.DOB,
  P.AGE,
  GETUTCDATE()
FROM PEOPLE P
LEFT JOIN (    -- pre-aggregate existing images and get the max number
    SELECT MAX(R.IMAGE_NUMBER) MAX_NUMBER
    FROM REGISTRATION R
    GROUP BY R.NAME
) R ON P.NAME = R._NAME
WHERE P.IS_ACTIVE = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Is there a way to compare each row and add max(R.IMAGE_NUMBER) to the person data before inserting it? That is if that particular number already exists?

Comment: That is exactly what it does already: it left-joins the existing `REGISTRATION` table to `PEOPLE`, aggregating by `NAME` and taking the max `IMAGE_NUMBER`. If it does not exists then we use `ISNULL`

Comment: Thanks again. sorry, I'm just learning... If I understand your code, it looks like it's always trying to insert. Is there a way to do what I was trying to do - which is to do an IF EXISTS before trying to insert? Sorry if my question sounds dumb

Comment: Sounds like you need a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` but the exact logic is unclear. Perhaps [edit] your question to explain the logic of what you are trying to achieve